# Excel: faster formula to find word that contains search string?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a bunch of text strings in Excel 2016.  I am trying to search for various substrings.  To be more helpful for reviewers, I want to return the word, delimited by spaces, which contains that substring.

For example, if my string is `Will be retiring in June` and my substring is `ret`, I would like the formula to return `retiring`.  This will allow reviewers to distinguish `retired` from `retiring` or `return`.

I have written the below formula.  There are multiple main strings to search.  They are in columns H - M.  There are multiple substrings to search for; they are in cells AQ1 - BF1.  I would like the found word to populate the AQ2 - BF60000.

AP1 will determine which main column to search.  If cell AP1 is H, then AQ2 will return the word that AQ$1 is found in from cell $H2.  If AP1 is changed to I, AQ2 would return the word from cell $I2.  This was simply to cut down on the number of formulas needed, looking at only one column at a time.

Here's a picture.

|  | H | I | ... | AP | AQ | AR | AS | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Work Status 1 | Work Status 2 | ... | H | ret | vol | unem | ... |
| **2** | Out on disability | FD volunteeer | ... |  | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | ... |
| **3** | Still unemployed | Returned April 2022 | ... |  | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | unemployed | ... |
| **4** | Hasn't returned, volunteering | Will be retiring 2023 | ... |  | returned | volunteering | #VALUE! | ... |
| **5** | Retired 2017 |  | ... |  | Retired | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | ... |

But if I change AP1 to be I instead of H, the table changes to

|  | H | I | ... | AP | AQ | AR | AS | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Work Status 1 | Work Status 2 | ... | I | ret | vol | unem | ... |
| **2** | Out on disability | FD volunteeer | ... |  | #VALUE! | volunteeer | #VALUE! | ... |
| **3** | Still unemployed | Returned April 2022 | ... |  | Returned | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | ... |
| **4** | Hasn't returned, volunteering | Will be retiring 2023 | ... |  | retiring | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | ... |
| **5** | Retired 2017 |  | ... |  | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | #VALUE! | ... |

The formula works, but it is a little slow, since I have about a million total cells to calculate.  Is there any way this could be optimized or rewritten completely?  This is a work project, so I have no ability to upgrade past Excel 2016 or install anything.

```
=MID(INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()),
```

This finds the beginning of the word (finds first space beforehand and adds 1).

```
     IFERROR(FIND("|",
                  SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()),
                                  SEARCH(AQ$1,INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()))
                                 ),
                             " ",
                             "|",
                             LEN(LEFT(INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()),
                                      SEARCH(AQ$1,INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()))
                                     )
                                )
                             - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()),
                                                   SEARCH(AQ$1,INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()))
                                                  ),
                                              " ",
                                              ""
                                             )
                                  )
                            )
                 ),
             0
            ) + 1,
```

This determines the number of characters from the start of the word to the end.

```
     SEARCH(" ",
            INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()),
            SEARCH(AQ$1,INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()))
           )
     - IFERROR(FIND("|",
                    SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()),
                                    SEARCH(AQ$1,INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()))
                                   ),
                               " ",
                               "|",
                               LEN(LEFT(INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()),
                                        SEARCH(AQ$1,INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()))
                                       )
                                  )
                               - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()),
                                                     SEARCH(AQ$1,INDIRECT($AP$1&ROW()))
                                                    ),
                                                " ",
                                                ""
                                               )
                                    )
                              )
                   ),
               0
              ) - 1
    )
```

Comment: I think you need to go the VBA or possibly power query route. I don't believe you would gain much speed using excel 2016 formulas, espcially since you are talking about 1M formulas. Maybe the only possibility of increasing performance using formulas is switching from `Indirect` to `index`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of data is terrifying, perhaps it can be divided into segments.
However, you can simplify formulas and use them as array formulas.
In the proposal shown below in the screenshot, there is one array formula for the entire range. I've defined the name "col" in the name manager to specify the selected data column.
Formulas need to be matched to the original data. Suggested modifications are shown in the screenshot.
An array formula entered in the range `F10:H13` was

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(col," ",REPT(" ",LEN(col))), 
FLOOR(SEARCH($F$9:$H$9, SUBSTITUTE(col," ",REPT(" ",LEN(col)))), 
LEN(col))+1, LEN(col)))
```

In Excel 2016 you should select the enire range and press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.
`Arkusz2` is the sheet name.
[image: keywords]

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this tomorrow at the office.  I did try separating the equation up into parts and saving them in the workbook.  It makes the file size HUGE, but it does make the formulas a lot faster.  I'll try your suggestion!

Comment: I tried this and it works well.  It takes about the same amount of time as when I split the huge formula up in to multiple parts without the drawback of the massive file size.

One odd thing is that I get the same results whether or not I make your solution an array formula.  Maybe because you defined the name "col" to be an array, Excel automatically treats all formulas like array formulas when used, whether or not Ctrl+Shift+Enter is used?

Comment: I actually got rid of all the array parts and just used regular references like $H2.  The formula isn't the same for every cell, but it works the same and will be easier for upkeep.  That's a smart algorithm, padding with blanks to make picking out words easier.  Thank you!

Comment: If you commit a formula with just `Enter`, you have to copy it in the entire range. And each cell has its own formula.
I suggested selecting the range, entering the formula into the first cell, and committing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` as a single array formula in the entire range. This should work faster with multiple cells, but I don't have enough data to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be any faster than VBA or Power Query for the amount of data, but it is a different approach using the `FILTERXML` function.

I added an `IFERROR` to return a blank if there is no match.
I also had to *lowercase* the strings since the *xpath* arguments are case-sensitive.

I also simplified the formula a bit by requiring that `AP1` contains the column **number** and not the column **name**.

I suggest you change the reference `$A:$M` to reflect the maximum possible number of rows and columns in your data array.  If you do that you would need to change the number in `AP1` so that, for example, if you used: `$H$1:$M$300000` then you would use a `1` in `AP1` to represent Column `H`.

```
AQ2: =IFERROR(
    FILTERXML(
        "<t><s>" &
            LOWER(
                SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($A:$M, ROWS($1:2), $AP$1), " ", "</s><s>")
            ) & "</s></t>",
        "//s[contains(.,'" & AQ$1 & "')] "
    ),
    ""
)
```

Then drag/fill across and down as far as needed.

***Data***
[image]

***Results with `H` (8)***
[image]

***Results with `I` (9)***
[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I will try this tomorrow.